# TimeoutException when trying to connect to Azure service bus queue through informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to load 2k records on azure service bus queue through informatica, but getting timeout exception. The connection is working file for 700 records, successfully loading on queue.

I have created JMS and JNDI connection and is working fine if number of records are less.

Error:

2020-05-04 23:27:28 : ERROR : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : JAVA PLUGIN_1762 : [ERROR] JMS writer encountered a JMS exception: Timed out while waiting to get credit to sendException Stack: javax.jms.JMSException: Timed out while waiting to get credit to send
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.send(MessageProducerImpl.java:331)
    at com.informatica.powerconnect.jms.server.writer.JMSMessageWriter$QueueWriter.writeMessage(JMSMessageWriter.java:93)
    at com.informatica.powerconnect.jms.server.writer.JMSWriterPartitionDriver.execute(JMSWriterPartitionDriver.java:401)
Linked Exception Stack: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.transport.ConnectionEndpoint.waitUntil(ConnectionEndpoint.java:1232)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.transport.SessionEndpoint.waitUntil(SessionEndpoint.java:686)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.transport.LinkEndpoint.waitUntil(LinkEndpoint.java:360)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.client.Sender.send(Sender.java:320)
    at org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.MessageProducerImpl.send(MessageProducerImpl.java:321)
    at com.informatica.powerconnect.jms.server.writer.JMSMessageWriter$QueueWriter.writeMessage(JMSMessageWriter.java:93)
    at com.informatica.powerconnect.jms.server.writer.JMSWriterPartitionDriver.execute(JMSWriterPartitionDriver.java:401)
.
2020-05-04 23:27:28 : ERROR : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : JAVA PLUGIN_1762 : [ERROR]     at com.informatica.powerconnect.jms.server.writer.JMSWriterPartitionDriver.execute(JMSWriterPartitionDriver.java:431)
2020-05-04 23:27:28 : ERROR : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : SDKS_38502 : Plug-in #300800's target [Target_jms: Partition 1] failed in method [execute].
2020-05-04 23:27:28 : INFO : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : WRT_8333 : Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session error.
2020-05-04 23:28:28 : INFO : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : WRT_8325 : Final rollback executed for the target [Target_jms] at end of load
2020-05-04 23:28:28 : ERROR : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : WRT_8081 : Writer run terminated. [Error in loading data to target table [Target_jms: Partition 1]]
2020-05-04 23:28:28 : INFO : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : WRT_8168 : End loading table [Target_jms: Partition 1] at: Mon May 04 13:58:28 2020
2020-05-04 23:28:28 : INFO : (3084 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | PC_INT_EE_QA) : node01_lxinfaeeqa1 : WRT_8035 : Load complete time: Mon May 04 13:58:28 2020

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it a bandwidth issue? Is your Azure account has unlimited bandwidth capability?

Comment: The queue size for azure was 1GB but it seems that it can only accept 100 messages in one transaction. I was able to solve the issue by changing properties at informatica session level. Commit type to "Traget" and commit interval to 100. And in target properties kept the JMS priority to 9.

Answer (score 0):

The queue size for azure was 1GB but it seems that Azure service bus queue can only accept 100 messages in one transaction. I was able to solve the issue by changing the properties at informatica session level. 
Commit type to "Target" 
commit interval to "100"
And in target properties kept the JMS priority to 9.